# JavaScript reverse words in the multiple lines

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
var text = document.getElementById('textarea').value.split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
document.getElementById('textarea').value = text;
```

It works when there is only one line:

```
LINE ONE > ONE LINE
```

but when there are multiple lines:

```
LINE ONE
LINE TWO
```

output is:

```
TWO ONE
LINE LINE
```

I want like this:

```
ONE LINE
TWO LINE
```

Comment: would be there only 2-word pair in each line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Split the array by the newline character `\n`, iterate each line with `Array#map`, and reverse it, then join the lines back with `\n`:

```js
var text = document.getElementById('textarea').value;
var result = text.split('\n').map(function(line) {
  return line.split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
}).join('\n');

document.getElementById('textarea').value = result;
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea">
LINE ONE
LINE TWO
</textarea>
```

Comment: :) Welcome are you

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `.replace( /\n/g, " " )` before the `.split(" ")`. You will get:

```
var text = document.getElementById('textarea').value.replace( /\n/g, " " ).split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
```

The reason this is happening, is that the array created by `document.getElementById('textarea').value.split(" ")` has the line break included with it. For instance, if you entered the following in the text area:

```
 1 2 3 
 4 5 6
 7 8 9
```

The array you that would be returned is ["9", "8", "6↵7", "5", "3↵4", "2", "1"]. Notice the return character at [2] and [4].

Your LINE ONE LINE TWO example would be ["TWO", "ONE↵LINE", "LINE"] before being reversed, and ["TWO", "ONE↵LINE", "LINE"] after being reversed. Then, when you .join() them back into a string, you get the very unexpected TWO ONE LINE LINE.

The  `.replace( /\n/g, " " )` will change those line breaks into spaces before you break up the string into an array, giving you the desired result.